# Pandas series - only keep value if index month is in [1,2,3]

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas.Series() object and I am trying to filter the data based on the month in the index. Here is an example Series object (index is ["2010-01-01", "2010-02-01", ..., "2016-06-01"]):

```
d = pd.Series(1, pd.date_range("20100101", periods=100, freq="MS"))
```

I would like to keep only items where the month is in a list of allowed months. For example, I'd like to keep only elements for which the index has month 1,2 or 3:

```
d[d.index.month.isin([1,2,3])]
```

However, d.index.month is an np.array, not a pandas.Series. I'm not sure how I can do this cleanly.

Comment: `d[d.index.month<=3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
d.loc[pd.Series(d.index.month, d.index).isin([1, 2, 3])]
```